# How do I select all checkboxes from a list of checkboxes (eg: ToDo List)

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a to-do list each item has a checkbox and I want to select each of these checkboxes when I click on them. If I click on any of them again the box should toggle between checked and unchecked depending on whichever box I click on.

I created this structure of input and an add button. When I click on the add button a table row gets added to the table(using **appendChild**). I created and appended the other elements required. So now when I click on the add button the table row displays correctly. It shows all the elements in it including the checkboxes.

The problem arises when I create multiple rows I can't select all the checkboxes. It works perfectly fine if only one checkbox is present. But for more than one checkbox all of the checkboxes don't get selected

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector(".search_add_container button");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputContent");
  var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
  var dataCell = document.createElement("td");
  var dataCellInnerContainer = document.createElement("div");
  dataCellInnerContainer.className = "data_cell_container";
  var tableCheckboxes = document.createElement("div");
  tableCheckboxes.className = "checkbox_box";
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "starGrey.png";
  img.alt = "starGrey";
  var cellHeader = document.createElement("h5");
  cellHeader.className = "cell_header";
  var cellTent = document.createElement("h5");
  cellTent.className = "cell_tent";
  var time = document.createElement("p");



  if (inputValue.value == "") {
    alert("Please add a note!");
  } else {
    cellHeader.innerText = inputValue.value;
    cellTent.innerText = inputValue.value;
    time.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: "2-digit"
    });
    table.appendChild(tableRow);
    tableRow.appendChild(dataCell);
    dataCell.appendChild(dataCellInnerContainer);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(tableCheckboxes);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(img);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellHeader);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellTent);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(time);

    inputValue.value = "";

  }

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".data_cell_container .checkbox_box");
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (checkbox.classList.contains("checked")) {
        checkbox.classList.remove("checked");
      } else {
        checkbox.classList.add("checked");
      }
    });
  });

  inputValue.value = "";
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr td {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.data_cell_container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px calc(250px - 80px) auto 65px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
}

.data_cell_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

.checkbox_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox_box.checked::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.cell_header {
  max-width: calc(250px - 100px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cell_tent {
  max-width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.data_cell_container p {
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="search_add_container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New List Item" id="inputContent">
    <img src="search.png" alt="searchicon">
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="table_container">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you want to add or remove a class `.checked` to every element? The easier solution would be to use the CSS `:checked` selector

Comment: Your changes here should _start_ with rewriting this so that it uses actual checkbox `input` elements, instead of trying to "fake" the functionality of the former using a mere `div` and added JavaScript logic. Chances are high that the usability will be much better if you use the _correct_ elements.

Comment: @tacoshy It was easier to design the checkboxes using 'div', but also I've done things like this before like click on text and add a line-through and it used to work. I don't really know why this code doesn't. I've selected all checkboxes, added an event listener. If that checked class exists don't add, otherwise add a checked class. Why does it fail though?

Comment: @CBroe I understand. I will make the necessary changes. But according to the code can you help me understand why it wouldn't work? because it's really bugging me.

Comment: It does not work, because you are adding multiple click handlers, which then start to cancel each other out. Every time your add button is clicked, you loop over _all_ the checkboxes that exist in the document at this time, and add a click handler to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you click the add button(under right circumstances,you know), each of the previous checkbox gets one extra event listener.
That is, for first time, it's ok, only one event listener for checkbox.

Second time, first checkbox gets two event listeners (which are essentially same) for the click event. So as soon as you check the checkbox, it gets unchecked(if checked, uncheck code you have).

Third time, first checkbox gets three event listeners which are essentially the same, so you click it, it gets checked and second event listener finds it checked so unchecks it and third event listener finds it checked so unchecks it.

So here is my suggestion to avoid accumulation of event listeners:

```
const addButton = document.querySelector(".search_add_container button");
const table = document.querySelector("table");
addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputContent");
    var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var dataCell = document.createElement("td");
    var dataCellInnerContainer = document.createElement("div");
    dataCellInnerContainer.className = "data_cell_container";
    var tableCheckboxes = document.createElement("div");
    tableCheckboxes.className = "checkbox_box";
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src="starGrey.png";
    img.alt="starGrey";
    var cellHeader = document.createElement("h5");
    cellHeader.className = "cell_header";
    var cellTent = document.createElement("h5");
    cellTent.className = "cell_tent";
    var time = document.createElement("p");



    if(inputValue.value == ""){
        alert("Please add a note!");
    }else{
        cellHeader.innerText = inputValue.value;
        cellTent.innerText = inputValue.value;
        time.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit" });
        table.appendChild(tableRow);
        tableRow.appendChild(dataCell);
        dataCell.appendChild(dataCellInnerContainer);
        dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(tableCheckboxes);
        dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(img);
        dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellHeader);
        dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellTent);
        dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(time);

        inputValue.value = "";

    }
    
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".data_cell_container .checkbox_box");
    let checkBoxIndex=0;
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      if(checkBoxIndex===(checkboxes.length)-1){
        checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if(checkbox.classList.contains("checked")){
                checkbox.classList.remove("checked");
            }
            else{
                checkbox.classList.add("checked");
            }
        });
      }
      checkBoxIndex++;
    });
  
    inputValue.value = "";
});
```

Why I used a new variable instead of `indexOf()` is because it returns not the desired value if multiple similar entities are there in the array. Same goes for `lastIndexOf()`.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Answer by @SuspenseFallback is better as actually you can omit the `forEach` method. However see my answer if you didn't understand why this happens.

Comment: thanks very much for the help. I understood your explanation well. I now see my error. Also yes SuspenseFallback code was a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have multiple click handlers on one checkbox. Instead, do this -

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector(".search_add_container button");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputContent");
  var tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
  var dataCell = document.createElement("td");
  var dataCellInnerContainer = document.createElement("div");
  dataCellInnerContainer.className = "data_cell_container";
  var tableCheckboxes = document.createElement("div");
  tableCheckboxes.className = "checkbox_box";
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "starGrey.png";
  img.alt = "starGrey";
  var cellHeader = document.createElement("h5");
  cellHeader.className = "cell_header";
  var cellTent = document.createElement("h5");
  cellTent.className = "cell_tent";
  var time = document.createElement("p");



  if (inputValue.value == "") {
    alert("Please add a note!");
  } else {
    cellHeader.innerText = inputValue.value;
    cellTent.innerText = inputValue.value;
    time.innerText = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: "2-digit"
    });
    table.appendChild(tableRow);
    tableRow.appendChild(dataCell);
    dataCell.appendChild(dataCellInnerContainer);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(tableCheckboxes);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(img);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellHeader);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(cellTent);
    dataCellInnerContainer.appendChild(time);

    inputValue.value = "";

  }

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".data_cell_container .checkbox_box");
  var checkbox = checkboxes[checkboxes.length - 1]
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (checkbox.classList.contains("checked")) {
        checkbox.classList.remove("checked");
      } else {
        checkbox.classList.add("checked");
      }
    });

  inputValue.value = "";
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr td {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.data_cell_container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30px 30px calc(250px - 80px) auto 65px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
}

.data_cell_container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

.checkbox_box {
  position: relative;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox_box.checked::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #BABCBE;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.cell_header {
  max-width: calc(250px - 100px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cell_tent {
  max-width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.data_cell_container p {
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="search_add_container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New List Item" id="inputContent">
    <img src="search.png" alt="searchicon">
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="table_container">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

Here, only the last element (the one just added) is selected.